# Python dict: the size affects timing?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Let' say you have one key in dictionary A vs 1 billion keys in dictionary B

Algorithmically a lookup op is O(1)

However, the actual time (program execution time) to look up different based on the size of the dict?

```
onekey_stime = time.time()
print one_key_dict.get('firstkey')
onekey_dur = time.time() - onekey_stime

manykeys_stime = time.time()
print manykeys_dict.get('randomkey')
manykeys_dur = time.time() - manykey_stime
```

Would i see any time difference between `onekey_dur` and `manykeys_dur`?

Comment: Constant time is constant.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: `dict` lookup is not O(1). It is *usually* O(1). It is O(m), with `m` being number of items in the bucket.

Comment: @Amadan - I never said it was, but if the OP assumes the algorithm is O(1) (which is constant time), then there should be no difference.

Comment: i've seen too many cases where theretical big O notation does not reflect the same way as the actual programming time of execution go. Wouldnt having to store many keys affect the memory usage of the machine and wouldnt the resource usage affect the programming time at all?

Comment: @JustinNiessner: even on the assumption that it really is O(1), O(1) time isn't necessarily constant. It's bounded above by a constant, that's not the same thing. Maybe it is faster for "one" than it is for "1 billion", but O(1) means even if so the trend doesn't continue indefinitely.

Comment: @SteveJessop - But that doesn't sound nearly as good as "Constant time is constant".

Comment: @JustinNiessner: yes, I think what you're seeing in these comments is that StackOverflow is partly populated with people who find it physically uncomfortable when the wrong thing sounds better than the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much identical in a test with a small and large dict:

```
In [31]: random_key = lambda: ''.join(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), 20))

In [32]: few_keys = {random_key(): np.random.random() for _ in xrange(100)}

In [33]: many_keys = {random_key(): np.random.random() for _ in xrange(1000000)}

In [34]: few_lookups = np.random.choice(few_keys.keys(), 50)

In [35]: many_lookups = np.random.choice(many_keys.keys(), 50)

In [36]: %timeit [few_keys[k] for k in few_lookups]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.25 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit [many_keys[k] for k in many_lookups]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.01 µs per loop
```

EDIT: For you, @ShadowRanger -- missed lookups are pretty close too:

```
In [38]: %timeit [few_keys.get(k) for k in many_lookups]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.99 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit [many_keys.get(k) for k in few_lookups]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.78 µs per loop
```

Comment: Note: A proper test would need to check both hits and misses; the number of probes required is generally higher for failed lookups, [according to this bug tracker entry.](https://bugs.python.org/issue10408#msg121139)